# Прошу помочь получить только уникальные значение

Tags: django, django-filter

В джанго проекте есть модель, но я должен получить только уникальные значение по названию, если название совпадают то пропускает не показывая его, уникальные значение только по имени(order) а не по айди и пк, спасибо

models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return order
```

views.py

```
OrderItem.objects.all()
```

спасибо

Comment: OrderItem.objects.all().distinct('order')

Comment: @AlioshcaZ Работает, спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Оформлю ответ для формальности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OrderItem.objects.all().distinct('order')
```